# Coc.nvim how to disable auto complete suggestions in markdown files?

Tags: vim, markdown, neovim, coc.nvim

I am trying to setup Neovim with Coc for writing markdown. I have Coc working with javascript and other file types.

What I am trying to do is disable the autocomplete suggestions only for markdown files. I have found that if I run `:CocDisable` that more or less gets the job done but I would like to keep markdown-lint enabled.

Is there a way to disable autocomplete suggestions in Coc only for markdown files?

[A picture of the autocomplete suggestions popping up in markdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akYWX.png)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`autocmd FileType markdown let b:coc_suggest_disable = 1`

This will disable completion suggestions only.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late here, but I believe the best method is to edit `CocConfig` file by putting `"suggest.autoTrigger": "none"`.

This more or less does the job OP is asking for.

Edit: typo, see reply 1

Answer (score 2):

You could write something like `autocmd FileType markdown :call CocDisable()` in your `.vimrc`